# Yeoman Angular, Load jQuery plugin

Tags: gruntjs, phantomjs, yeoman

I want to include a jquery plugin ([jPushMenu](https://github.com/takien/jPushMenu)) in my yeoman's angular app.
I've included the script in my index.html but when i run grunt i get this error:

PhantomJS ERROR
  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery

The script is

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that i've put the plugin inside the scripts library. when i moved it to be under the app directory it works fine